# Handle AuraHandledException in Lightning Web Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Let's say I have an apex method like such:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void myMethod(String myString){
    if (String.isBlank(myString)) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Not Cool Bro.');
    }
}
```

and I have a Lightning Web Component with controller with a method like this:

```
import myMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.myMethod';

export default class YeOldeWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track myString;

callMyMethod() {
    console.log("Starting my method...");
    myMethod({myString: this.myString})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("My Method Was Successful!");
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("My Method Was Not Successful :/");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        let myMessage = "Default Error Message.";
        this.showToast("Error!", myMessage , "error");
    });
}    
showToast(theTitle, theMessage, theVariant) {
                const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: theTitle,
                    message: theMessage,
                    variant: theVariant
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
```

How do I get something useful (the original error message) out of the 'error' variable to pass to the showToast method?

------EDIT ------
I figured it out... it goes a little something like this:

```
.catch(error => {
        let errorMessage = TOAST_MESSAGE_ERROR;
        if ( error.body.message) {
            errorMessage =error.body.message;
        }
        this.showToast(TOAST_TITLE_ERROR, errorMessage, TOAST_VARIANT_ERROR);}
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, not sure if you've read [ask] and [answer] before, but they may be worth a quick read. Please post your discovery as an **`Answer`** rather than an edit. You can accept another answer if someone else provides something better. But putting the answer in your `Question` body is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it figured out - it looks like this!

```
.catch(error => {
    let errorMessage = TOAST_MESSAGE_ERROR;
    if ( error.body.message) {
        errorMessage =error.body.message;
    }
    this.showToast(TOAST_TITLE_ERROR, errorMessage, TOAST_VARIANT_ERROR);}
```